# Accessing Global Bamboo variables in inline shell script

Tags: bamboo, confluence

I am using Bamboo 5.6.2

I am defining a plan global variable named "cd" and willing to access it as part of inline script task.

I have tried

```
  echo $BAMBOO_CD
  echo `$BAMBOO_CD`
  echo "$BAMBOO_CD"
  echo $BAMBOO_cd
  echo `$BAMBOO_cd`
  echo "$BAMBOO_cd"
```

But none of them are printing anything. 
I have already gone through https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO056/Defining+global+variables

Appreciate pointers or an alternative way to define things globally.

I do not have an option of upgrading Bamboo at this stage to use advanced features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you declare dev as global variable . In inline script , you can access using $bamboo_dev

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the case. It worked after replacing BAMBOO with bamboo i.e. $bamboo_cd

Comment: What do you mean "dev as a global variable?" OP asked for "cd" as the variable?